# google speech to text dependency gives errors at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-speech-api

I am trying to use google speech to text api using java spring boot. In their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize) it askes to add the following dependency to the pom file to download the needed dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
  <version>0.46.0-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

This can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries).

When I build and run the project, the project gets started normally.

But when I call the method containing `SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create()` below exception is thrown.

```
io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: No functional channel service provider found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-okhttp or grpc-netty artifact
```

Then I added that dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
</dependency>     

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Once I added that dependency also and try to build, a BUILD FAILURE occurred as follows telling me that could not resolve the added dependencies.

```
 Failed to execute goal on project tts-samples: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.texttospeech:tts-samples:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE: Failed to collect dependencies for com.example.texttospeech:tts-samples:jar:2.0.1.RELEASE: Could not resolve version conflict among [com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:jar:0.47.0-alpha -> com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:1.29.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.10.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.10.1, com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:jar:0.47.0-alpha -> com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:1.29.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.10.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.10.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.10.1, com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:jar:0.47.0-alpha -> io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.10.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.10.1,1.10.1], com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:jar:0.47.0-alpha -> io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.10.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:1.10.1, com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:jar:0.47.0-alpha -> io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.10.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.10.1,1.10.1], io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:jar:1.11.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.11.0,1.11.0], io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:1.11.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.11.0,1.11.0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By breaking down the last error you posted, it looks like the conflict is actually in the versions rather than in the dependencies. (Note the 2 lines surrounded with ***:

```
com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:jar:0.47.0-alpha
    io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.10.1, io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.10.1, io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.10.1
        ***io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.10.1,1.10.1],*** 
io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:jar:1.11.0, io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:1.11.
        ***io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.11.0,1.11.0]***
```

The `google-cloud-speech` library you are using depends on libraries that depend on the grpc-core `1.10.1` while the new dependencies are using grpc-core `1.11.0`. Change the versions from 1.11.0 to 1.10.1 and the problem might be solved. You will have something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.1</version>
</dependency>     

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried that also. Then also same BUILD FAILURE occurred.

Comment: Oh, I double checked the error now, the error is in the versions. I have updated the answer.

Comment: it worked. thank you so much. the issue was at grpc versions. now the project get build successfully. but at run time following error occurs once this line in my code executed;   "SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create()"

Comment: 2018-05-28 23:06:06.280  WARN 6446 --- [nio-2233-exec-1] io.grpc.okhttp.internal.Platform         : Unable to find Conscrypt

Comment: do you have any idea on it?

Comment: I've never come across that error. You should probably ask that as a separate question so that someone else that has encountered that issue may be able to help.